# mysql insert into indexed table taking long time after few million records

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, load-data-infile

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dnddata` (
  `numbers` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `opstype` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numbers`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (numbers)
PARTITIONS 25 */;
```

i have to insert 300 million records. i am inserting 10 million records each time using `load data in file` from csv file.

To insert 10 million records taking nearly 5 min first time. Time is increasing each time gradually. after 30 million records it stops inserting and memory using 100% server not responding.

below my `my.cnf` file setting

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 100M
key_buffer = 100M
sort_buffer_size = 50M
read_buffer = 50M
```

i am using cpu with 2 G memory.

details for 30 million records

```
    Space usage
Type    Usage
Data    545.3   MiB
Index   694.8   MiB
Total   1,240.1 MiB

MySQL client version: 5.5.14
```

with out index it is inserting fine 10 million in 50 sec.

Please tell me what kind of setting need to change.

Comment: Do 'numbers' need to be varchar? An index on an integer column would certainly be more efficient.

Comment: @sam. numbers has to be varchar. because these are mobile numbers, value exceeding the int value.

Comment: you can possibly use BIGINT instead it's still faster than varchar.

Comment: @Omesh, Some times i may get values with characters also. i can change it for char if it's improves performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE dnddata DISABLE KEYS;

LOAD DATA INFILE...

ALTER TABLE dnddata ENABLE KEYS;
```

Also configure my.cnf as:

```
key_buffer_size = 1G
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 2M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
```

restart MySQL server after modifying MySQL config file.

formula below might help you configure parameters properly:

```
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size) * max_connections = K bytes of memory (< 2GB)
```

do you really need numbers as varchar(10)? making it char(10) or int will help improve performance.

creating PRIMARY KEY on a varchar column is overhead so you can drop it if its not needed.

Comment: Thank you for response. i will try and post the feedback.

Comment: i tried above setting. even though no use. i have waited more than 10 min for 10 million. it's not completed.

Comment: I have edited my post. try disable keys, then load data and enable keys.

Comment: i tried disabeling keys. even though no use. i hour is over still happening. so killed..

Comment: try changing ENGINE=MEMORY and set tmp_table_size=1.5G max_heap_table_size=1.5G and then load data. *NOTE: Memory table loses data after server restart.

Comment: hi Omesh, i can't use memory engine. we have 300 million records basically these dnd number. i have tried innodb also. but no use. we are upgrading our server. let me see any luck..